# How to verify the sha256 result of integer 5 in the Zokrates tutorial?

Tags: string, hash-algorithm, integers, zokrates

The Zokrates tutorial [here](https://zokrates.github.io/sha256example.html) starts with calculating the SHA256 hash of (the number) 5.

The hex representation of the result is shown at the bottom here:

[image]

However, I could not reproduce this on my ubuntu 18.04 command line:

```
(venv3.6) ~/zokrates_tutorial$ echo 5 | sha256sum
f0b5c2c2211c8d67ed15e75e656c7862d086e9245420892a7de62cd9ec582a06  -
```

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a convincing verification via [this](https://blog.decentriq.ch/proving-hash-pre-image-zksnarks-zokrates/) link.

In python there exists a function that turns a hex string into a byte representation like so:

```
>>> preimage = bytes.fromhex('00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00\
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05')
```

from which then the hex digest can be computed:

```
>>> hashlib.sha256(preimage).hexdigest()
'c6481e22c5ff4164af680b8cfaa5e8ed3120eeff89c4f307c4a6faaae059ce10'
```

which is indeed the same a in the tutorial.